# Fullpage.js with different html files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I want to load the contents of different html files in those sections on scroll and when `view page-source` is clicked then it should show the HTML of page loaded in the section. Example section#2 contains the HTML from page#2.html

The url should have

> mysite.com/page-2

When FB share button on Page#2 is clicked,. FB should scrape the 
og tags of page#2.html

Like this website: https://theoffshorepartners.com/

I have checked fullpage.js but it only works with single html page.
Please help me.

Comment: you could use ajax to make a get request out to the page in question, load the data into a variable, and then parse that data to grab what you need (maybe the whole page, maybe just some of it)

Comment: @Rockafella Thank for suggesting, I have already done the same thing.